# Doctrine find related records without foreign keys

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two preexisting tables that were created by a CMS. I've mapped them in Symfony2 and I am trying to establish a relationship between two of the tables but I am now noticing that the CMS created these tables without a foreign key. This table `table_uploads` has a column that every other table is related to called `column_table_name` and `column_record_num`.

So assuming we have three tables... `table_students`, `table_uploads`, and `table_teachers`, the table `table_uploads` will have a value of either `students` or `teachers` in `column_table_name` to show its relation to the other two tables as well as a number in `column_record_num` that corresponds to the other table's primary key. Neither of the three tables actually have a defined foreign key however.

In Symfony, I'd like to call a table

```
$students = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SchoolBundle:Students')->findAll();
```

and then load the related records from another table in such a way like (I know `select_related` doesn't actually exist, but this is essentially the functionality I'm looking to create)

```
$students->select_related()
```

Is this at all possible without the existence of a foreign key? The only way I can think of doing it is grabbing the column values from `$students` and running another query to other table with these values and merging the two results.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom repository method that would join unrelated tables. [DQL join between unrelated entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060555/dql-join-between-unrelated-entities)

Comment: This seems to be working but I can't get pull the information together. For instance,`createQuery('SELECT a FROM Users a JOIN Uploads b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.name='name_here')` gives me the values for `Users` and changing it to `SELECT b` gives me the values for `Uploads`. If I do `SELECT a,b` I get a giant array with rows from both tables. Is there away to have an organized array with rows from Uploads is inside of Users? Or to call the Uploads rows in the template while looping through Users?

Comment: If you could add relationships tho those tables, that would be the best solution.